# React is not showing posts of request.user in Django Rest Framework

Tags: reactjs, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, axios

I am building a Blog App in `Django` and `React` and I am trying to get posts only of `request.user`, and In `Django Rest Framework` Dashboard (api as json) posts are perfectly showing of request.user But when i try with `axios.get()` in `React Frontend` then it is showing nothing.

views.py

```
class BlogView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Blog.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

        return queryset
```

serializers.py

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('id','user'','title', 'description')
```

React - App.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    let data;
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/`).then((res) => {
        data = res.data;
        this.setState({
            blogs : data.map((blog) => {
                return Object.assign({}, blog, {
                    title : blog.title,
                    description : blog.description,
                    });
                }),
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
    };
```

users.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'blogs', views.BlogView, 'blog')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

I have tried many times but accessing it using `filter(user=self.request.user)` but it didn't worked for me.

When I refresh React Page then it is showing

> [16/Feb/2022 14:05:21] "GET /api/blogs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2

in Django Server.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Can we see your URLs around API

Comment: @FaisalNazik, I have uploaded the `urls.py`

Comment: How can i pass an `ID` if there's no in `url` in backend ?